# For angular 2 what do I need to have imported into my component for routerLink to work on my view

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

For angular 2 what do I need to have imported into my component for routerLink to work on my view?

I think I need to import something from my @angular/router? And then add it to my components directive?

But I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS

RouteConfig to configure routes and Router for navigation

Update : Routes for @angular/router

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html

**Update** Not sure if this you wanted! : https://i.imgsafe.org/55d36e1e91.png

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from  '@angular/router';

import { Comp1 } from  './comp1';
import { Comp2 } from  './comp2';
import { Comp3 } from  './comp3';
import { Comp4 } from  './comp4';
import { Comp5 } from  './comp5';

@Component( {
    selector: 'root',
    template: `<h1>ROOT Component</h1>
    <a [routerLink]="['/comp1']" >Comp1 </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/comp2']" >Comp2 </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/comp3']" >Comp3 </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/comp4']" >Comp4 </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/comp5']" >Comp5 </a>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ], providers: [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ]

} )

@Routes( [  
    {path: '/comp1', component: Comp1 },
    {path: '/comp2', component: Comp2 },
    {path: '/comp3', component: Comp3 },
    {path: '/comp4', component: Comp4 },
    {path: '/comp5', component: Comp5 }

] )

export class Root  { }


bootstrap( Root );
```

**compX.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component( {
    selector: 'comp1',
    template: `<h1>Child Component1</h1>
    `
} )

export class Comp1  { }
```

Comment: I'm using @angular/router not @angular/router-deprecated

Comment: I've got my routes setup in app.component but having trouble with my other components when using routerLink in the view

Comment: I have done this so far: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ROUTER_PROVIDERS-let.html but routerLink doesnt work in my other components. what do i need to import in my other components so they can use my app.component routes?

Comment: I've followed your answer but it doesnt work for the components view

Comment: I got it working, I had a spelling mistake on the route name. your code worked above.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the documentation. There are constants - [ROUTER_PROVIDERS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ROUTER_PROVIDERS-let.html) and [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ROUTER_DIRECTIVES-let.html).

Ensure which router you want to use. Till beta version there was a version which is [deprecated in RC1](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html).

Comment: I'm currently using this version:  @angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: Do i use @Routes instead of @RouteConfig?